# Django. I need variables from my own context processor only when user is authenticated

Tags: python, django

I have Django 1.8.13. I need variables from my own context processor only when user is authenticated. My context processor:

```
def comment_rew(request):
   context_dict = {}
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
      user = request.user
      user_rew = user.review_set.all().count()
      context_dict['user_rew'] = user_rew
   return(context_dict)
```

When user is not authenticated it returns an empty dictionary and that causes an error(because context processor can't returns an empty dict). Is it possible to use context processor only if user is authenticated?

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: My question is not about an error. It's about "Is it possible to use context processor only if user is authenticated?" The empty dict causes an error because context processor can't returns an empty dict. In my case dict is empty when user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context processors can't be enabled/disabled based on the authentication status of users.

You can instead set the value of the context variable `user_rew` to `None` when users are not authenticated:

```
def comment_rew(request):
    context_dict = {'user_rew': None}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        user_rew = user.review_set.all().count()
        context_dict['user_rew'] = user_rew
    return context_dict
```